# ListBoxes and Values in Cells

Tags: excel, for-loop, listbox, userform, vba

Below I have code for a command button in my userform. I have two listboxes (lb1 and lb2) and a couple text boxes (t1, t2, t3, t4). The items in the listbox are names of each sheet in the workbook. If there are items selected in the lb1, the items transfer to the lb2.

Then the button is supposed to place an output (t3) and use the cell range given in a t4 and the sheet names from the selection in lb2 to loop through the selected sheets and place the output. Sorry if this is confusing but the code will hopefully clarify.

```
    Private Sub c4_Click()
    Dim CellName As Variant
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim lb1 As ListBox
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    CellName = t4.Value


       '## If this item is selected, then give it a new value name
    For n = 0 To Me.lb1.ListCount - 1
        If Me.lb1.Selected(n) = True Then
        Me.lb2.AddItem Me.lb1.Selected(n)
         End If
    Next n

    For i = 0 To lb2.ListCount - 1
    sht(Me.lb2.ListIndex).Range("(CellName)").Value = t3.Value
    Next i
'Loop through selected listbox sheets to add output

End Sub
```

Comment: `the code will hopefully clarify` not if code is bad. Speaking of which, why is it bad? What's the question/problem?

Comment: The last part won't finish. It won't take the lb2 values and use them in the sht(...) loop. The objective is to put values into every sheet that was selected from the list box. I do not know how to loop through the selected sheets if I cannot reference the multiple values selected in the list box. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes but I am going home so sorry! But +1 hopefully to encourage anther to help you.